# Does independent variable X, if represented in interval have an effect on regression model

Tags: regression

In all the example of linear regression model I have studied X is taken as fixed value ( midpoint of interval). Can we have a regression model in which X is in interval form and how this will affect regression analysis. And how this will affect condition mean.

Comment: Yes, such models have been formulated.  What are you willing to assume about $X$?  What does an interval form for it mean, exactly?  Will $X$ also be a random quantity or not?  If so, what will you assume about its distribution?

Comment: I am asking whether x values can be continuous i.e in intervals like 100-120, 120-140.... or it takes only discrete values like 115, 130 ...

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "interval form"?  Are you referring to values that are actually ranges of numbers or do you mean the so-called "interval" data type (a continuous variable whose numerical differences are meaningful)?  You seem to be using *both* meanings in your question!

Comment: Interval i.e. continuous data type.